# What path to images to use with CKEditor to insert images in content?

Tags: wysiwyg

When putting images in content items, I have to put the full URL, otherwise images don't show up.

It works for this full path:

```
http://localhost/IT/sites/default/files/mypictures/apache_pb.png

<p><img alt="" src="http://localhost/IT/sites/default/files/mypictures/apache_pb.png"/></p>
```

But doesn't work for this path:

```
sites/default/files/mypictures/apache_pb.png

<p><img alt="" src="sites/default/files/mypictures/apache_pb.png" /></p>
```

I know I must be missing something? A token? Variable to path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the forward slash: /sites/default/files/mypictures/apache_pb.png

Incidentally, IMCE will make this easier for you.